# Is there any idea on how to print a pattern only if the user inputted the number of row and column?

Tags: php

I don't have any idea if how I am  going to print a pattern, only if I input the number of row and column, help me guys, send your code

```
<?php  

    if (isset($_GET['row']) && $_GET['column']) {
        $row = $_GET['row'];
        $column = $_GET['column'];
        $output ="*";

        for ($i=$_GET['row']; $i <=1 ; $i++) { 
            for ($j=$i; $j <=$_GET['column']; $j++) { 
                $count = $i;
                if ($i == $j) {
                    echo $count. " ";
                }else{
                    echo $count +=4;
                }   echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }



?>
```

here is what I want to have

Enter Row : 5
Enter Column : 4

Output:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Comment: `send your code` is not how SO works. Please explain what your code currently does and what it should do?

Comment: This look more like a homework/challenge/quiz for students than an actual project. Please refer to the link to know how to ask a question about homework: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way with the help of [**array_fill()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) and [**implode()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). The `array_fill()` function fills an array with values of `*` here and `implode()` join the stars to a single string.

```
// $_GET = ['row' => 5, 'column' => 4];

if (isset($_GET['row'], $_GET['column']) && $_GET['row'] > 0 && $_GET['column'] > 0) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $_GET['row']; $i++) {
       echo implode('', array_fill(0, $_GET['column'], '*')) . PHP_EOL;
    }     
}
```

[**Working demo.**](https://3v4l.org/3TRqD)